# Selecting records that have specific count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to breakdown a query even further to elaborate on resultset.
I have a table `Log` [image]

I run this script on every morning.

```
SELECT [90DayTally] = COUNT(AssociateName)
, AssociateName
, Supervisor
FROM [DailyAttendance].[dbo].[Log]
Where  EventDate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -90)
group by AssociateName, Supervisor
having COUNT(associatename)>4
Order By [90DayTally] Desc
```

Which gives management a visualization of who is messing up (LOL) So this is the result from query.

```
90DayTally  AssociateName       Supervisor
7           Carlos Silva        Karla Vivas
6           Luz Carmen Garcia   Cynthia Perez
5           Daniel Lockington   Damian Vasquez
```

I also would like to show upper management what exactly these colum counts are. 
Below i am showing an example of what i want to see and the rudimentary way i am having to acheive this now

```
 select *
 FROM [DailyAttendance].[dbo].[Log]
 Where EventDate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -90)
 and AssociateName in ('Carlos Silva', 'Luz Carmen Garcia', 'Daniel Lockington') 
 order by AssociateName Asc
```

This is working showing these results but i am having to do this every morning and change out the `AssociateName` Very tedious.

[image]

I have tried a subquery but apparently incorrectly.Is there a way i can acheive this without having to type in each `AssociateName` under where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your existing query as a subquery and replacing the hard coded values of your IN clause.

Something like this maybe:-

```html
select *
FROM [DailyAttendance].[dbo].[Log]
Where EventDate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -90) and AssociateName in (
SELECT AssociateName FROM (
SELECT [90DayTally] = COUNT(AssociateName), AssociateName, Supervisor
FROM [DailyAttendance].[dbo].[Log]
Where  EventDate >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, getdate()), -90)
group by AssociateName, Supervisor
having COUNT(associatename)>4
) AS DATA 
) order by AssociateName Asc
```

Comment: Close to what i had tried. This works just need to remove the `order by` clause from sub. Thanks